# How can I stop unwanted e-mails from Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I am not a Facebook customer.  How do I stop emails from people who want to be my friend & other  annoying emails from Facebook?

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately there's nothing you can do to stop people sending you e-mails.

You could try contacting Facebook and ask them to remove you from any mailing list they hold, but I suspect the e-mails are from your friends and acquaintances who are using the "use your address book" option to see if anyone *they* know is interested in joining.

The best you can do is set up an e-mail filter that looks for certain words in the subject or body of the e-mail ("Facebook" itself would seem to be a good place to start) and automatically route those to a separate folder or even delete them immediately. How you set this up will depend on your e-mail client.

I'd recommend routing them to a separate folder where you can check them from time to time to make sure you're not missing an important message from someone that just happens to mention "Facebook".

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the gear icon in the upper right, and click "Account Settings"
2. Then click "Notifications" in the left sidebar
3. Then click "Email"
4. And click the radio button for "Only notifications about your account, security and privacy"

That should handle most unwanted email.